# how to assign a value to label of a view from controller using codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I use the following code to display a login form in html view part

```html
<form action="/TestApp/index.php/my_controller/validate" method="POST" method="GET">
  Username: <input name="name" type="text"><br />
  Password: <input name="word" type="password"><br />
  <label name = "error"></label><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

inside controller I validate username and password. The following lines of code help me to get textbox values into controller.

```html
$uName = $_POST['uname'];
$pWord = $_POST['pword'];
```

I need to assign/set string value to label error from controller.

How can I do that? please help me.

Controller

```
class My_controller extends CI_Controller {

public function login()
{
    $this->load->view('login_view');
}

    public function validate()
    {
        $this->load->model('login');



        if((isset($_POST['name'])) && (isset($_POST['word'])) && !empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['word']))
        {
            $uName = $_POST['name'];
            $pWord = $_POST['word'];

            if($this->model_users->checkUser($uName) == 1) {
                if($this->model_users->checkPassword($uName) == $pWord) {
                    echo 'Loggedin!';
                    $this->session->set_userdata('login_state', TRUE);
                } else {
//                        Incorrect password;
                    redirect( '/' );
                    $error = "Incorrect password!";
                }
            } else {
//                    Username does not exist;
                redirect( '/' );
                $error = "Username does not exist!";
            }
        } else {
//                Username or Password field is empty;
            redirect( '/' );
            $error = "Username or Password field is empty!";
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Check this : https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

action should be

```
action="<?php echo base_url() ?>my_controller/validate"
```

> In `autoload.php` load **url helper** as well

an in validate method

```
$uName = $_POST['name']; # not uname
$pWord = $_POST['word']; # not uname
```

---

**To pass date to view**

**In Controller**

```
$data['error'] = "My Message here";
```

**In View**

```
if (!empty($error)) {
    ?>
    <label name ="error"></label>
    <?php
}
else{

}
```

Comment: my action works fine. i need to know how to assign a value to the label from controller

Comment: @user3002114 check now

Answer (score 0):

The controller part code with validation

```html
<?php

class Form extends CI_Controller {

 function index()
 {
  $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

  $this->load->library('form_validation');

  $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'name', 'required');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'word', 'required');
  
  if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
  {
   $this->load->view('myform');
  }
  else
  {
   $this->load->view('formsuccess');
  }
 }
}
?>
```

Comment: no. i am asking how to assign a value to label `<label name = "error"></label>` in the view from controller

Answer (score 0):

> try this

inside the view

```
 <?php echo form_open('my_controller/validate', ['method'=>'post']) ?>
```

inside the controller

```
$uName = $this->input->post['name'];
$pWord = $this->input->post['word'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct this,

In controller

```
$uName = $this->input->post('name');
$pWord = $this->input->post('word');

if($uName == "" || $pWord == ""){// change the conditions if required.
    $error = 1;
} else {
    $error = 0;
}
$data['error'] = $error;
$this->load->view("view_name",$data);
```

In view

```
if($error) { 
    echo "<label>Error has occurred</label>";// change error if required.
}
```

If you are trying with redirect, use `flashdata()`.
In controller.

```
$this->session->set_flashdata("error","error message here");
```

In view

```
if($this->session->flashdata("error"){
    // echo label here
}
```

Comment: i couldn't use `$this->load->view("view_name",$data);` because i already loaded view. This is only the function to validate login. Need to set value to that label on submit button click

Comment: edited question and added functions of controller. I assign error messages  that i need, into `$error` variable. My validation codes are working fine. the thing I need is, set value of `$error` to label of the view.

Comment: you want to use `redirect()`??

Comment: i have no idea about what `redirect()` do. It would be fine if it solve this issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94912/discussion-between-user3002114-and-niranjan-n-raju).

Comment: @user3002114 check the chat.